# Mudar a cor dos itens de menu quando passar o mouse

Tags: html, css

Quero mudar a cor da escrita dos itens de menu. Do jeito q eu fiz a cor muda quando eu passo a seta em cima da letra, mas eu queria q a cor da letra do menu mudasse logo quando eu passar o mouse em cima do background-color.

```css
/* Formataçao do menu */

nav#menu {
  display: block;
}

nav#menu h1 {
  display: none;
}

nav#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20;
  left: 300px;
}

nav#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #dddddd;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

nav#menu  li:hover {
  background-color: #606060;
}

nav#menu a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav#menu a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="specs.html">Especificações</a></li>
   <li><a href="fotos.html">Fotos</a></li>
   <li><a href="multimidia.html">Multimídia</a></li>
   <li><a href="fale-conosco.html">Fale conosco</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só alterar o último seletor de `nav#menu a:hover` para `nav#menu li:hover a`. Isso irá apontar para a tag `a` que está dentro da `li`. E alterar as propriedades das `li` e do `a` para que o link ocupe toda a dimensão da `li`, tornando a `li` clicável por inteiro.

Ou seja, o `padding: 10px` sai da `li` e vai pro `a`. E as propriedades `display: inline-block`, e `top`, `right`, `bottom` e `left` com valor `0` fará com que o `a` ocupe toda a área da `li`:

```css
/* Formataçao do menu */

nav#menu {
  display: block;
}

nav#menu h1 {
  display: none;
}

nav#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20;
  left: 300px;
}

nav#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #dddddd;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

nav#menu  li:hover {
  background-color: #606060;
}

nav#menu a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav#menu li:hover a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="specs.html">Especificações</a></li>
   <li><a href="fotos.html">Fotos</a></li>
   <li><a href="multimidia.html">Multimídia</a></li>
   <li><a href="fale-conosco.html">Fale conosco</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: top, right, bottom e left por padrão ficam com qual numeração?

Comment: Ficam com `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Minha opniao o melhor jeito e estilizar a tag A e nao a LI, assim voce consegue o efeito que precisa de forma simples.

```css
/* Formataçao do menu */

nav#menu {
  display: block;
}

nav#menu h1 {
  display: none;
}

nav#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20;
  left: 300px;
}

nav#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav#menu a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  /*trecho que estava no nav#menu li*/
  background: #dddddd;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

nav#menu a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #606060;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="specs.html">Especificações</a></li>
   <li><a href="fotos.html">Fotos</a></li>
   <li><a href="multimidia.html">Multimídia</a></li>
   <li><a href="fale-conosco.html">Fale conosco</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```